# How to remove the extra indent on list after the 10th item in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I want to remove the extra indentation that appears on a list after the 10th item:

```
8. This is a line
9. This is a long line that gets wrapped to the next 
   line because it has a lot of characters
10.    This is a line that gets wrapped too, but has a
   weird indentation at the beginning.
```

I want them to have all the same indentation, like this:

```
9.  This is a line
10. This is a long line that gets wrapped but now it has
    the same indentation as the line before
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to move the left indent over a bit so that the two-digit numbers don't overflow.

[image: snippet of Google Doc]

Do you notice in the ruler, the small rectangle and the down-pointing triangle?

[image: "First Line Indent" and "Left Indent"]

Those define the "First Line Indent" and the "Left Indent". If the number is too wide, it forces the indent to jump to the next default tab stop. You need to move them further apart.

[image: after indent moved further from indent marker]

Highlight all the text you want this to happen to (otherwise it'll only work on the line where the cursor is) and drag the triangle to the right. That'll also move the rectangle, so drag the rectangle back to where you wanted it. There will be guide lines so you can line it up with existing text.

As you can see, it handles multi-line items just fine.

[image: indent with multi-line items and 2-digit list numbers]

Answer (score 2):

Much easier, first make sure your list goes past 10 and has the issue, then select all bullet points and text, then click the button that changes the list to bullet points, then change it back to a numbered list. Google Docs at least notices the issue and indents things properly.

Answer (score 0):

ale's answer is almost complete. However, it does not address when you have sub items. A list along the lines of this:

```
  1. Main point 
      a. sub one 
      b. sub two 
  2. Another point 
      a. sub sub 
      b. sub marine
```

When you select the list and change the indent, it changes it for **EVERYTHING**. Even the sub points.

However, if yo click carefully on the main point numbers, you can select just them and **not the text**. Then use the ruler to move the numbers back with the blue over bar. If you want to move the whole indent and keep the .25 inch spacing, move the blue arrow over to about .56 or so, which moves everything, then move the bar back to .25. That will keep the number indent a quarter of an inch on any print results.

If your sub points need adjusting, you can then select the sub points. If doing an abc there, it is unlikely you need to do this added work.